# Unable to loop through collection of laravel in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-maps

Hello I am working on Google Maps and i have collection of lat, long form database, through these lat, long i have to create markers.

Laravel Collection:

```
public function getMap()
{

    $map = Map::all();
    return view('view-map',
        compact('map'));

}
```

JavaScript Code:

```
    <script>

var data = {!!$map!!};
var i;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


//var lat = {{$map->lat}};
//var lng = {{$map->lng}};
var lat = data[i]->lat;
var lng = data[i]->lng;

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center:{
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
    },
    zoom: 15
 });

  // Marker
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

  position:{
    lat: lat,
    lng: lng
  },
  map: map

  });
} // end for
</script>
```

This is creating only single marker how to loop through all lat, long in javascript, please guide me.

Comment: Googling "javascript loop" would be a good start like reading about [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: @GillesC I have updated the code using for loop but ErrorException in Collection.php line 1527:
Property [lat] does not exist on this collection instance, this is error

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are creating new maps and replacing the current one for each iteration. Try instead only creating markers for each iteration:

```
<script>

 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center:{
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
    },
    zoom: 15
 });

var data = {!!$map!!};
var i;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

  // Marker
  var lat = data[i]->lat;
  var lng = data[i]->lng;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

    position:{
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    },
    map: map

  });

} // end for

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Dear Laravel and JavaScript are two different thing.
there are multiple aproaches that you can use.

1. You can fetch the markers with ajax.
2. you can do  `var data = <?=  var_dump($map) ?>;`
3. there is also a package available which simply let developer to inject the php variable to javaScript. `"laracasts/utilities": "~2.0"`